# Disable input only when modified by system

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

This code does a search and displays the results.  I want to conditionally disable `input`s.I am using knockout to control when an `input` is disabled.

Requirement:

1. `input` is disabled when set by the system.
2. User input should not be disabled.

In the following code input that comes from `readDatabase()` works well.  If the user types in the Hometown/Nickname `input`then tabs out then `input` disables.  How can I fix this code to meet the second requirment?

**Update**

I am not opposed to getting some help from jQuery.  I do not want to throw out my view model binding entirely.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/7X8x7/1/)

HTML

```
Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: userInput, valueUpdate: 'input'" /><br />
Hometown: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Hometown, disable: Hometown" /><br />
NickName: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Address, disable: Address" />
```

JavaScript

```
 function MyViewModel() {
         var self = this;
         self.userInput = ko.observable();
         self.Hometown = ko.observable();
         self.Address = ko.observable();             

         self.userInput.subscribe(function () {
             readDatabase(self);
         });
     }
     ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());

function readDatabase(self){
    if(self.userInput().substring(0,1) == "a"){
        self.Hometown("A town");
        self.Address("A address");
    }
    else {
        self.Hometown("");
        self.Address("Other address");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) to provide a flag indicating where the data came from:

```
ko.extenders.isServerSet = function (target, value) {
    target.isServerSet = ko.observable(value);
    return target;
};

function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.userInput = ko.observable();
    self.Hometown = ko.observable().extend({
        isServerSet: false
    });;
    self.Address = ko.observable().extend({
        isServerSet: false
    });;
    self.userInput.subscribe(function () {
        readDatabase(self);
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());

function readDatabase(self) {
    if (self.userInput().substring(0, 1) == "a") {
        // don't overwrite user-provided values
        if (!self.Hometown()) {
            self.Hometown("A town");
            self.Hometown.isServerSet(true);
        }
        if (!self.Address()) {
            self.Address("A address");
            self.Address.isServerSet(true);
        }
    } else {
        self.Hometown("");
        self.Address("Other address");
    }
}
```

```html
Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: userInput, valueUpdate: 'input'" /><br />
Hometown: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Hometown, disable: Hometown.isServerSet" /><br />
NickName: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Address, disable: Address.isServerSet" />
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/7X8x7/2/)